# WinForms DataGridView clearing SelectedRows when I set a cell value?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I am modifying the value of a DGV cell programmatically.  For some reason, this is clearing the SelectedRows property of the DGV.  Here is my code:

```
1:  public static void WriteDGVCellValueByRowAndCol<T>(DataGridView dgv, int row, int column, T newValue)
2:  {
3:      dgv.Rows[row].Cells[column].Value = newValue;
4:  }
```

Seems pretty straightforward, I thought.  Unfortunately, this is what happens when I trace through using a break point and the debugger:

- Before line 3 executes, debugger shows dgv.SelectedRows.Count == 1
- After line 3 executes, debugger shows dgv.SelectedRows.Count == 0

The DGV itself remains intact, and the cell value is getting updated, but the SelectedRows property is being emptied so that its Count is 0.  Why would this happen, and what might I do to prevent it?

**Edit**

This only appears to occur after also changing the selected row programmatically from another form.  E.g., if I set the current `Rows[n].Selected = false;` and then set `Rows[n+1].Selected = true;`, then the above function fails in the way described.  However, if I do *not* perform this selection modification first, no error occurs (the SelectedRows property remains intact).

For the meantime, I'm working around this issue successfully with the following update to the function, but it does not seem like it should be necessary, so I'd love any help figuring out what is causing this strange effect.

```
1:  // Workaround
2:  public static void WriteDGVCellValueByRowAndCol<T>(DataGridView dgv, int row, int column, T newValue)
3:  {
4:      dgv.Rows[row].Cells[column].Value = newValue;
5:      dev.Rows[row].Selected = true;
6:  }
```

For purposes of clarity, here is the function being used to modify the selection programmatically:

```
private void SelectNext()
{
    int currentIndex = myDGV.SelectedRows[0].Index;
    int newIndex = currentIndex;
    if (currentIndex == myDGV.RowCount - 1)
    {
        Log("The last row was already selected.  Wrapping to the first row.");
        newIndex = 0;
    }
    else newIndex++;

    myDGV.Rows[currentIndex].Selected = false;
    myDGV.Rows[newIndex].Selected = true;
}
```

This function is being passed to another form using `Func<...>` and works as expected, except for this `SelectedRows` side effect.

Comment: SelectedRows is still `1` in my test. Could you add more detailed steps that can 
 reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes, was adding new details as you requested them.

Comment: Test with your newly added description, there is still no "SelectedRows issue". This seems to be a very accidental issue. Try to report a problem on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=61).

Comment: I have not tested your code, however if Kyle Wang is not having the same issue, is it possible that some “other” events you may have wired may be cascading? Example, setting a cells value even programmatically is going to fire the `CellValueChanged` event and probably others as well. Have you traced this?

Comment: @JohnG that was it.  Thank you.  This programmatic change is causing the DataBindingComplete event to be fired, and I am modifying the DGV SelectedRows in there.  Thank you for the hint.